# mChart android color not changing

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am using Mphil chart lib, I have added this code for my line chart.

But its not changing the color, its showing default purple color, is there something i missed or error in my code

```js
  LineDataSet set1;
        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();



        } else {
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "");
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setLabel("");
            set1.setDrawValues(false);
            set1.setHighLightColor(R.color.extracyan);
            mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
            // set1.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            //set1.enableDashedHighlightLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            set1.setColor(R.color.extracyan);
            set1.setCircleColor(R.color.extracyan);
            set1.setLineWidth(3.5f);
            set1.setDrawCircles(false);
            set1.setCircleRadius(3.5f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(0f);
            set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER);
            set1.setDrawFilled(false);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(2.5f);
            set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);

            /*if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_blue);
                set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
            } else {
                set1.setFillColor(R.color.cyan);
            }*/
            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSets.add(set1);
            LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
            mChart.setData(data);
            progresslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           txtProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

I tried adding diff color, diff method, but still the same, I tried adding 2 set with diff color but change , they both where in same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add *multiple* **colors** for your `charts` by this:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);
            for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);
            for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);
            for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);
            for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);
    set1.setColors(colors);
```

replace this code by  `set1.setColor(R.color.extracyan);` that.